# nvcc : fatal error : Option '--cubin (-cubin)' is not allowed when compiling for multiple GPU code instances

Tags: opencv, cuda, ptx

Attempting to compile the GPU module of OpenCV 2.4.8 with VS2010 on a Win7 x64 machine with GTX760, CUDA v5.0, the following error appears after each object build routine:

nvcc : fatal error : Option '--cubin (-cubin)' is not allowed when compiling for multiple GPU code instances

what does this mean?  should i change something in my CMake params before building?

I am building on top of a working library, just trying to get CUBLAS built and recognized by my application so I can use gemm for subspace projection.

Comment: UPDATE: I cleared the cache in CMake (which updated the "CUDA_ARCH_BIN" flag) and unchecked "CUDA_BUILD_CUBIN".  The generated solution is now building with no issues.  Elementary.

Comment: please add that as an answer to your question (it is perfectly OK to answer your own question here on [SO]). Later, you can accept that answer, which will get the question off the unanswered queue and make the solution easier to find for the next person that comes along with the same probalem. Thanks.

Comment: got it.  had to wait for an interval because my account is so new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: I cleared the cache in CMake (which updated the "CUDA_ARCH_BIN" flag) and unchecked "CUDA_BUILD_CUBIN".  The generated solution is now building with no issues.  Elementary.